# which architecture or design patterns are suitable for this application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, architecture

I am researching for an architecture for creating an application in C++ to process multiple inputs at the same time in different cores. Each input is processed in a single core simultaneously. Each of the process on a core, the same filters will be processed through. For example: filter1.apply(), filter2.apply() and filter3.apply(). The processes are illustrated for 4 cores for 4 inputs as below:

```
[core 1]   [core 2]    [core 3]   [core 4]
   |          |            |         |     
   V          V            V         V
  input1     input2      input3     input4
   |          |            |         |    
   V          V            V         V 
 filter1    filter1     filter1    filter1
   |          |            |         |    
   V          V            V         V 
 filter2    filter2     filter2    filter2
   |          |            |         |    
   V          V            V         V 
 filter3    filter3     filter3    filter3
   |          |            |         |    
   V          V            V         V 
 output1   output2      output3    output4
```

I dont know which architecture or design pattern is suitable for this. It would be great if you give me some artifacts (documents or sample application) to read further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Joachim: thanks for your edition. Actually, I was making it better as well :)

Comment: Just as a side note, it looks like if you could somehow compile the filter sequence into a single filter then that might be a net win, since you're always doing the same sequence of things - a bit like display lists in OpenGL.

Comment: compiling the filters in a single filter is not nice because the scope (number of lines) of a function is very big. and I would like this architecture in the future to be more flexible of adding new filters. e.g: filter 4 and filter 5 are added then I just simply called: filter1.apply(), filter2.apply(), filter3.apply(), filter4.apply() and filter5.apply().

Comment: Fair enough - there's often a performance/flexibility trade-off.

Comment: If the filters are very special purpose a DSL might be helpful. That way you can also optimize filter expressions at compile time.

Comment: These filters - do they operate on a complete input buffer in one go and pass the complete output to the next filter, or is there a continual stream of buffers?  Where does the original input come from - files, video input, network.. what?

Comment: there is an input buffer. first in first out. the output of filter 1 will be the input of the next filter and so son. the inputs are images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually thread pools are used to implement such designs. They scale virtually infinitely for independent processes. You can find easy implementations in TBB and PPL. They offer concurrency-related versions of many Standard algorithms and containers. For example, in this sample I've used `concurrent_vector`, which is a `vector`-like container which can be safely mutated from several threads concurrently, and `parallel_for_each`, which runs the function on many threads at once.

```
concurrent_vector<output> outputs;
std::vector<input> inputs;
parallel_for_each(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), [](input& input) {
    outputs.push_back(filter3(filter2(filter1(input))));
});
```

Comment: Just to add something, If you dont know a priori how many iterations or tasks you have, TBB also offers a nice feature called parallel_do which "cooks till done".

Comment: I am not sure if I use this because the input of this filter is the output of the next filter. the input is an image array but it is not union, they can be either of types: int, float or char. I dont know whether this one is a suitable one?

Answer (score 0):

I think "Strategy method" is helpful.
In each core, puts each filter as an object to a vector, like:

```
std::vector<filter> filters;
```

then

```
std::for_each(filters.begin(), filters.end(), [input&](f&){f.apply(input);});
```

====================

We iterate by filter, not input. So we can add/del filter at runtime.

like:

```
class YourCore {
public:
    void add_filter(const filter& f) {m_filters.add(f);}
    // void del_filter(int index);
    // void del_filter(by name or UID, so change vector to map or unordered_map);
private:
    std::vector<filter> m_filters;
};
```